# Unique compound index in MongoDB throwing DuplicateKeyException on first time insertion

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I have created a compound index on a collection in mongo db using mongo-java-driver(3.6.3).

```
IndexOptions indexOptions = new IndexOptions().unique(true);
mongoCollection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("f1","f2"), indexOptions);
```

On insertion of a record,

```
mongoCollection.insertOne(dBObject);
```

The driver is throwing a DuplicateKeyException even though there is no record in the database with same f1 and f2.

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: db-test.test1 index: f1_1_f2_1 dup key: { : "testf1", : "testf2" }
```

If I check the record in the database through mongodb-client, the record is inserted in the database. 
Yet the application code gets the exception.